# OPA5-Tests doesn't work with multibinding at one Label

Tags: sapui5

I try to implement Opa5-Tests. When I start it with the "standard" process via IFrame everything works and all Tests run successful. Because of different Problems I wanted to change the startup to the Component method like this.

```
        Given.iStartMyUIComponent({
        componentConfig: {
            name: "com/test/questionairy"
        },
    });
```

Principally everything works but wen I try to bind two different Properties of a Model to one Label like this

```
<Label class="viewHeader" text="{= ${userModel>/nname} ${userModel>/vname}}"/>
```

or

```
<Label class="viewHeader" text="{userModel>/nname} {userModel>/vname}"/>
```

this, the view lost the Binding and doesn't show the data. The App itself runs normal and everything is fine just the Tests runs to fail because the data is Missing. Has everybody an idea, what's the Problem.

[image: Datamodel with the Correct Properties and Values]

[image: Screenshott of the Binding Path from the F12 UI5 Inspector]

Comment: Hi Patrick, have you tried checking how your model / data is loaded? Run time in chrome under networks when you press f12 make sure metadata is loaded.

Comment: Hi jasbir, yes I have checked. Te data and the model get loaded correct till the moment of the rendering. I will attach two screenshoots to show the bindig string got changet while the rendering and the data are valid in my opinion.

Comment: Hi have you included this in the index.html file  data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"

Comment: Hi yes I have this inside my index

Comment: Sorry this was the Problem i changed the wrong index  thanls for your help

Comment: Cool, I wondered why wouldn't work :)